# What is the point of the "Locked" attribute in Highlight Properties in Adobe Acrobat DC?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

What is the point of the "Locked" attribute in Highlight Properties in Adobe Acrobat DC?

[image]

I understand that it greys out the Highlight Properties GUI fields, but what is the point in doing so?

I use Adobe Acrobat DC Version 19.10.20099.322322 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is the point of the "Locked" attribute

It stops you (accidentally) removing the highlight:

[image]

Source [The Lawyer's Guide to Adobe Acrobat](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=i3MTpopI4-sC&pg=PA93&lpg=PA93&dq=acrobat%20%20what%20are%20%22locked%22%20%22highlight%22%20properties&source=bl&ots=nxIDwhWCKr&sig=ACfU3U1q39RbM6hNyJtFZMvz6ieCWBoBKw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKuf7Yp-ziAhUATxUIHXBNAhkQ6AEwDXoECDEQAQ)